# React Native: Rendered more hooks than during previous render by useRef in react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

In my RN 0.62.2 app, there is an error after the declaration of animated value is changed to use `useRef`. The code without error was:

```
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {Value} from Animated;

const dragX = new Value(0);
```

Since it is functional component and I am following the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/value) of `react-native-reanimated` to added `useRef`:

```
const dragX = useRef(() => new Value(0)).current;
```

After change, then the line above throws error:

Tried the following and the problem is the same:

```
const dragX = useRef(new Value(0));
```

Tried `useValue` and the error is the same. There aren't much information about how to use `useRef` in `react-native-reanimated` other than the doc linked above.

[image]

UPDATE:

The code is too long and messy. The method `displayImg` is to display a single image in area which is defined by its parent component. If there is more than one image (dateLen > 1) in parent component, then each and every image displayed by `displayImg` will be able to drag and requires animation. `useRef` is being used to maintain the status after each re-rendering.

```
function displayImg (img_source, width, ht, index, modalWidth, modalHt, dataLen, sortFn) {
        const aniIndex= new Value(index);
        const aniGridPR = new Value(gridPerRow);
        const dragX = useRef(new Value(0)).current;  //<<==this line causes error
        const dragY = new Value(0);
        const offsetX = new Value(0);
        const offsetY = new Value(0);
        const state = new Value(-1);
        const scale = new Value(1);
    var gridPerRow;
    console.log("image width : ", width);
    console.log("image ht : ", ht);
    if (dataLen <= 4 && dataLen > 1) {
        gridPerRow = 2;
    } else if (dataLen > 4) {
        gridPerRow = 3;
    } else {
        gridPerRow = 1;
    };
    
            
    function onUp ([x, y, indx, gridPR]) {
        console.log("In on Up");
    };
            
    
    if (img_source && img_source!==[] && img_source!=={}) {
        if (dataLen == 1) {
            const scale = new Value(1);
            function onGestureStateChange() {

            };
            /* const onGestureStateChange = event([
                //{nativeEvent:set(nativeEvent.scale, scale)},
            ]); */
            let scaleStyle = {
                transform:[
                    { perspective: 500 },
                    {
                        scale :  scale
                    }
                ]
            };
            return (
                <><PinchGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={onGestureStateChange}>
                    <Animated.View style={scaleStyle}>
                    <GridImage
                        img_source={img_source}
                        width={width}
                        ht={ht}
                        index={index}
                        modalWidth={modalWidth}
                        modalHt={modalHt}
                    />
                    
                    {/* <DeleteButton index={index} /> */}
                    <ModalImage
                        img_source={img_source}
                        modalWidth={modalWidth}
                        modalHt={modalHt}
                        index={index}
                    />
                    </Animated.View>
                    </PinchGestureHandler>
                </>
                );
        } else {
            console.log("ani code");
            
            const addX = add(offsetX, dragX);
            const addY = add(offsetY, dragY);
            const transX = cond(eq(state, State.ACTIVE), addX);  //set(offsetX, addX)
            const transY = cond(eq(state, State.ACTIVE), addY, 
                                    cond(eq(state, State.END), 
                                        cond(or(greaterOrEq(abs(divide(dragX,new Value(width))), new Value(0.3)), greaterOrEq(abs(divide(dragY,new Value(ht))), new Value(0.3))), 
                                            call([addX, addY, aniIndex, aniGridPR], onUp))
                                        )
                                    );
                                    //, [ set(dragY, new Value(0)), set(dragX, new Value(0))]
            const handleGesture = event([
                {
                  nativeEvent: {
                    translationX: dragX,
                    translationY: dragY,
                    state,
                  },
                }, 
              ]);
            
            let aniStyle = {
                transform:[
                    { translateX : transX },
                    { translateY : transY },
                    
                ]
            };
            
            return (
                <>
                  
                    <PanGestureHandler 
                        onGestureEvent={handleGesture} 
                        onHandlerStateChange={handleGesture}
                        minPointers={1}
                        maxPointers={1}>
                        <Animated.View style={[aniStyle ]}>
                        <GridImage
                            img_source={img_source}
                            width={width}
                            ht={ht}
                            index={index}
                        />
                        </Animated.View>
                    </PanGestureHandler>
            
                {/* <DeleteButton index={index} /> */}
                <ModalImage
                    img_source={img_source}
                    modalWidth={modalWidth}
                    modalHt={modalHt}
                    index={index}
            />
                
                </>
                );
        };
        
    } else {
        return null;
    };
    
};
```

Comment: Please, show the full code. This problem usually is because do you make something before useRef that change the state or execute something in the first render that also changes the state, like call a "setState".

Comment: The code is long and messy. Sorry.